# embedded resources available in design time, not runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, markup, embedded-resource

I am using [this markup extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files?msg=4054362#xx4054362xx) together with resx files for globalization / localization. The basic idea is that given a fully qualified resx file name and key, you can markup your xaml like so:

```
    Title="{Resx MyAssembly.MyResources.MyView Key=Window_Title}"
```

It works very well when the resx files are in the same assembly as the view, but oddly when they are in another assembly; I can see the resx values perfectly in design time (the visual studio editor) but NOT at runtime.

The code is a bit complex, so I am hoping this might be enough to troubleshoot with.

Cheers,